# Hostname is available yet doesn't show up in Azure Portal for purchase

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice, custom-domain

Hello I can see that hostname (domain) is available on 3rd party providers like GoDaddy etc, however i am unable to purchase it from Azure App Service domain page on portal

here i am trying to purchase Sandeep.com, as you see in screenshot the hostname is available where as it is not showing up in Azure portal from available list of domains. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a known issue and Product Group is working to fix this along with new UI for App Service Domains that's currently in preview as seen below:

[image: ASD Portal View]

PFB work around to purchase desired available hostnames on Azure Via CLI:

•   Please go to portal->click on Azure CLI besides search bar as seen below:

[image]

•   I selected powershell as seen below:

[image]

•   Here, I am trying to buy “nihakoneru.com” which is not an option through portal as seen below:

[image]

•   However, I was able to verify that this domain is available for purchase by running below command in Azure CLI:
"az appservice domain show-terms --hostname nihakoneru.com"
[image]

Here is the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/domain?view=azure-cli-latest) that has list of commands to use through CLI, I now replaced the values in the [JSON file](https://github.com/AzureAppServiceCLI/appservice_domains_templates/blob/master/contact_info.json) with my contact information (Name, Email, Address etc) from the above doc as seen below and saved it to my local.

[image]

•   Now let’s go back to the portal->cli and upload this file to cloud shell by clicking on the highlighted below:

[image]

•   You will see pop up message as below once the file is uploaded:

[image]

PFB final command used to purchase domain:

[image]

Once the above command is being executed, you will see the state as running for a bit until the process is completed in the backend:

[image]

Once the domain purchase is completed you will see the status changing to Finished as below:

[image]

I was able to verify that my domain was purchased by going to App Service Domains on portal as seen below:

[image]

I hope this helps in the interim as a workaround.